# Whats the process for downgrade an installation of 2sxc

Tags: 2sxc

Recently I upgraded 2sxc but some things stopped work, so i would like to start downgrading 2sxc to try.

I found this information https://azing.org/2sxc/r/6z3lel3k and says i can try to downgrade, but there is not the process or steps for downgrade.

What is the process. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I improved the checklist https://azing.org/2sxc/r/6z3lel3k so it now has more detailed explanations.

Comment: Thanks for the information, i will check the process